# Is it impossible to run SharePoint application(SharePoint dll for 2007) in SharePoint 2016 installed PC

Tags: sharepoint-server

I made a sharepoint winform application(reference Microsoft.SharePoint.dll version 12.0)

I registered that dll using gacutil.

But In my PC, SharePoint 2016 is installed, So in Visual studio, build and run is okay.

When I try to run some button event, exception occured like this

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.SharePoint.Library,
>   Version=12.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=71e9bce111e9429c' or
>   one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

So I think the problem is the different dll between my PC SharePoint(version 16)

and Application`s SharePoint(version 12). Is that right?

If that is right, is it impossible to run in my PC?

Please somebody help me

Answer (score 0):

you have to extract the dll's from the server where 2007 version of SharePoint is installed and refer that in your application. deploy the same in the gac as well.

I did the similar way where the installed software is wss 3.0 but referring older version of sharepoint 2001/wss 2.0 for some migration purposes.

This will work without any issues.